# Comment s'appellent les bulles dans les bandes dessinées ?

Tags: vocabulaire, demande-de-mot

Y a-t-il un nom particulier donné aux bulles utilisées pour faire parler les personnages dans les bandes dessinées ?

Je parle de ces bulles-là: [image: Bulle]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Le nom technique pour les bulles de bandes dessinées est « [phylactère](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phylact%C3%A8re#Dans_les_bandes_dessin.C3.A9es) ».

Answer (score 14):

Le nom usuel pour les bulles de bandes dessinées est « [bulle](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulle#Bande_dessin.C3.A9e) ».